# Asp.net web api From uri e From Body quando utilizar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Asp.net web api para que serve [FromBody] e [FromUri] e quando existe real necessidade de utilizar ?

exemplo:

```
  public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] email)
  {

  }

  public IHttpActionResult Get([FromBody] email)
  {

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São dois atributos para você deixar explícito qual vai ser o binding de parâmetro que sua API vai utilizar. Por padrão, o framework vai mapear quase todos objetos como um JSON que venha no corpo da requisição (DateTime, Guid, são exemplos de objetos que ele vai tentar pegar da URI), e todo tipo simples/primitivo como um valor que vai vim na URI da requisição. Logo, se você deseja fazer o inverso, você precisa especificar de onde esta vindo a requisição.

Exemplo, se você deseja receber uma string que venha no corpo da sua requisição, você deve especificar para a API: `public IHttpActionResult GetPessoaPorNome([FromBody] string pessoa) {}`